# Find value of a the divides area into 2 equal parts

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have an enclosed area between the curves $f(x)=-x^2+4$ and $g(x)=-x^2/4 + 1$. There is a horizontal line $y=a$ that splits the area into 2 equal parts. I cannot figure out what value of $a$ would make it equal. So far, I have only worked with a quadratic being cut by horizontal line, but this one is a quadratic being cut by another quadratic. I have been able to figure out that the area is 8 but the fact that both are curved is making it difficult. Any help is appreciated!  Here is an image of the figure:

[image: diagram]

Comment: Fix $a\ge 1.$ Compute the area above $y=a.$ That means the area between $y=a$ and $y=4-x^2.$ Then solve the equation that the area is equal $4.,$

Comment: Are you saying that $a>=1$ because it would split the area into 3 sections? Would the problem still be solvable if I did not include that?

Comment: It seems from your picture that $a>1$  If you change the proportion of the division, for example the upper part is $7$ times the lower part then we will have to take $a<1$ into account as well.